# How to create a textbox to contains IPv4 address?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

how to make a text box like this?

[image]

I think all of use have seen this before and know its features.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a MaskedTestBox with Mask `000\.000\.000\.000`.

For more info see [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx).

Comment: Does not work. Only works for a full xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ip address.  "123.4.5.6" becomes "123.456.."