# how to get textboxt that takes ip address type values in it

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I want to take ip address type value in my textbox just like this in windows network and sharing centre tab of windows. How to do that in my winforms application in c#.
 [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a textbox to contains IPv4 address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601846/how-to-create-a-textbox-to-contains-ipv4-address)

Comment: See: [flexfieldcontrollib](https://github.com/m66n/flexfieldcontrollib) on GitHub. IPv4 and IPv6. License status unclear.